# Can we check the device to be smartphone by using bluetooth in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, detect, smartphone

The issue is when my flutter app is in bluetooth scanning mode it is detecting all the devices so i need only smartphone to detect using my app and other devices like smarTv,smartwatch and bands and headphones i need to reject them in my flutter app

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to conclusively detect only smartphones and display them. When advertising with BLE, many devices use the "GAP Appearance" flag to specify their type (e.g. phone, computer, tag, clock, etc), but not all devices follow this convention, and many devices don't use this tag, so you are bound to display devices that are not smartphones.

For more information, have a look at the following links:-

- [How Bluetooth Low Energy Works: Advertisement](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-low-energy-advertisements-part-1/)
- [BLE Specification Generic Access Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/)
- [BLE Specification GAP Appearance](https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml)

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Yossif Saeed 
But there will be an issue , the same app should to be need in two smartphone devices then only we can detect the bluetooth devices in our app by using advertising 

**If the same app is not there in two smartphone (i.e A & B)devices also it will work ???**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you mean that you will need your app in two smartphones then it shouldn't make a difference, because using the GAP Appearance is a generic BLE thing. However, as I said in my answer this is not a conclusive way of differentiating devices because many devices don't use this GAP Appearance.